# Is it possible somehow run sync loop with Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

So I have simple loop with function which retunr `Promise`. Looks it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    parseCategory(categories[i]).then(function() {
        // now go to the next category
    })
}
```

Is it possible somehow to wait until first function will be ended and the iterate to next element?

P.S.
It's not necessary to use promises.

Comment: Try google for "promise waterfall". This should be, what you want here. (sorry, currently have not the time to draw up a complete answer)

Comment: Here's a good article on how to do it without 3rd party libraries: https://remysharp.com/2015/12/18/promise-waterfall

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in ES6 without a library:

```
var parseCategoryPromise = Promise.resolve();
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
  (function(i){
    parseCategoryPromise = parseCategoryPromise.then(function(){
      return parseCategory(categories[i])
    });
  })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Promises, why not go all the way? The best Promise module, Bluebird, has a helper function specifically designed to iterate across an array, in series, with promises controlling the execution: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html. You use it like this:

```
Promise.mapSeries(categories, function(category) {
    // Parse the category, and return a value or a promise.
});
```

If parseCategory is a function defined elsewhere, you can even get more brief:

```
Promise.mapSeries(categories, parseCategory);
```

There is also a `map` sister function that executes the calls in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

With await/async support you'd be able to do it pretty easily:

```
async function parseCategories (categories) {
  for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    await parseCategory(categories[i])
  }
}
```